# Sql Trigger to add new row when table update

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am new to sql triggers and learning as developing triggers for asp.net application.i am having case where I need to first save table and then edit the same table - this edit create new row in different table but the the problem is every time I edit the table it create new row in different table I want to create row in different table for only first edit.

Dividing my problem for readability.

I have two tables:
Table A and table B

I have written trigger on table A that add row in table B.

Problem:
Every time I edit row in table A a new row get added to table B. (So every edit create new row)

Required result:
I want my trigger to add ONLY one row in table B for the first edit in table A but not for subsequent edits.

I am using update triggers.
Any example with code would be great 
Thanks you much in advance .

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[triggerName] ON [dbo].[databaseName]
For Update
As
Begin
DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @d int
DECLARE @action char(6)
DECLARE @Car VARCHAR(20)

IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) RETURN

SELECT @i = Count(*) From Inserted
SELECT @d = Count(*) From Deleted

SELECT @action = CASE 
WHEN (@i <> 0) and (@d <> 0) THEN 'UPDATE'
WHEN (@i = 0) and (@d <> 0) THEN 'DELETE'
WHEN (@i <> 0) and (@d = 0) THEN 'INSERT'
End


SELECT @Car = A From inserted


IF @action = 'UPDATE' AND @Car in ('BMW')

   Begin
    INSERT INTO Tableb (c,d,f)
    Select c,d,f from inserted
   End
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Show your code.

Comment: Are you sure you should be creating a trigger for that? As far as I understand the trigger will become obsolete as soon as one row has been added to table B. You might want to re-think your database setup / design.

Comment: @zohar I have added code for review

Comment: @Ralph I don't think of any other way might be because of my limited knowledge as I am using triggers in response to update in Table A which create a row in Table b.i do not know what is the right way.please guide

Comment: You should (at least) setup a daily job to delete all triggers which have outlived their useful lifespan (such as this one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger has some flaws in it.

First, You don't need to test if it was fired because of update, insert or delete. The trigger is specified for update, so inserts and deletes will not fire it anyway.

Second, `SELECT @Car = A From inserted` will raise an error whenever you update more then one row in the table.

Third, As you said, this will insert a record in tableB for every update, while you want it to insert a record only for the first update done (I assume one for the first update on any row, so if you update row 1 then insert, update row 2 then another insert, and update row 1 again don't insert).

I would write it like this:

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[triggerName] ON [dbo].[tableName]
For Update
As
Begin

    INSERT INTO Tableb (c,d,f)
    Select c,d,f 
    from inserted i
    left join Tableb t ON(i.c = t.c and i.d = t.d and i.f = t.f)
    where t.id is null -- or some other non-nullable column
    and i.a = 'BMW'

End
```

Comment: Thanks Zohar for your help and sharing your knowledge. I am  but accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your SQL trigger to execute only after INSERT

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.myTable_Insert
 ON dbo.myTable
AFTER INSERT
AS
```

It is possible to [create SQL trigger](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-trigger-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) to run after insert, update or delete as seen in the referred tutorial

Comment: sorry now i have added my code.I am using update trigger to add new row.